# How do you add bullets without using a list?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-selectors

Havent touched html/css in years so I need some help. I have a nested list, and want to style the outer list (`#todo`), and just have 'normal' bullets on the inside list (`#task`). Problem is when I style the outer list it automatically styles the inside list as well. As a rigged fix, i thought of removing the `li` tags from and just making them `<p>` and somehow add a bullet to the front of them. How do you add bullets to the front of `<p>` tag?

```css
#parent .todo ul li:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: -25px;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px solid #0bb5f4;
}



#parent .todo ul li:after{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: -21px;
    width: 2px;
    height: 75px;
    background: #0bb5f4
}

.task{
    padding-left: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="todo">
    <div class="title">
        <p class="bold">Title1</p>
    </div>
                        
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="date">today</div>
            <div class="info">
                <p class="semi-bold">Name</p>
                <p class="description"><em>location</em></p>
                <div class="task">
                     <p>task1</p>
                     <p>task2</p>
                     <p>task3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
                            
        <li>
            <div class="date">yesterday</div>
            <div class="info">
                <p class="semi-bold">Name2</p>
                <p class="description"><em>location2</em></p>
                <div class="task">
                    <p>item1</p>
                    <p>item2</p>
                    <p>item3</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a class on the `li` elements of the outer list and apply the styles you want to apply on the outer list, on this class. This way, inner list's `li` elements won't be styled.

```css
.outer-li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

.outer-li::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: -25px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #0bb5f4;
}

.outer-li::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  left: -21px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #0bb5f4
}
```

```html
<div class="todo">
  <div class="title">
    <p class="bold">Title1</p>
  </div>

  <ul class="outer">
    <li class="outer-li">
      <div class="date">today</div>
      <div class="info">
        <p class="semi-bold">Name</p>
        <p class="description"><em>location</em></p>
        <ul class="task">
          <li>task1</li>
          <li>task2</li>
          <li>task3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="outer-li">
      <div class="date">yesterday</div>
      <div class="info">
        <p class="semi-bold">Name2</p>
        <p class="description"><em>location2</em></p>
        <ul class="task">
          <li>task1</li>
          <li>task2</li>
          <li>task3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could use `::before` pseudo selector.

```css
li {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

li::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: -25px;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #0bb5f4;
}

li::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 14px;
  left: -21px;
  width: 2px;
  height: 75px;
  background: #0bb5f4
}

.task {
  padding-left: 25px;
}

.task p {
  position: relative;
}

.task p::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #222;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  left: -13px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="todo">
  <div class="title">
    <p class="bold">Title1</p>
  </div>

  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="date">today</div>
      <div class="info">
        <p class="semi-bold">Name</p>
        <p class="description"><em>location</em></p>
        <div class="task">
          <p>task1</p>
          <p>task2</p>
          <p>task3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed.